# Getting absurd errors in using template template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have been trying to create a templated class(`Test2`) that takes 2 template arguments,`Type1` and `Type2`. It is known that the second argument would also be a templated class that takes 2 template arguments(`TypeA` and `TypeB`).

Now, for constructing an object of `Test2`, I want the user to be able to use either of 2 types of constructors:

1. One that takes objects of  `Type1` and `Type2`.
2. One that takes objects of `Type1`, `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class TypeA, class TypeB>
struct Test
{
    TypeA t1obj;
    TypeB t2obj;
    Test(const TypeA& t1, const TypeB& t2)
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(t2) {std::cout<<"Test::Type1, Type2\n";}
};


template<class Type1,
         template<typename TypeX, typename TypeY> class Type2 >
struct Test2
{
    Type1 t1obj;
    Type2<typename TypeX, typename TypeY> t2obj; //Line 17

    Test2(const Type1& t1,
          const Type2<typename TypeX, typename TypeY>& t2) //Line 20
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(t2) { std::cout<<"Test2::Type1, Type2\n";}

    Test2(const Type1& t1,
          const TypeX& x,
          const TypeY& y)
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(x,y) { std::cout<<"Test2::Type1, X, Y\n";}

};

int main()
{
    Test<int, char> obj1(1,'a');

    Test2<int, Test<int, char> > strangeobj1(10,obj1);
    Test2<int, Test<int, char> > strangeobj2(1,2,'b');

}
```

I have tried a lot but I get really absurd errors like:

`wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)` on Line 17 and 20.

Comment: Make sure you post the _first_ error message. The rest might be bogus. And please indicate its line in the code.

Comment: @sbi: The error I mentioned is the first error I get.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your description, so I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. `Test<int, char>` is a full blown *type*, instead of a *template*. So you need type parameters

```
template<class Type1,
         class Type2 >
struct Test2
{
    Type1 t1obj;
    Type2 t2obj; //Line 17

    Test2(const Type1& t1,
          const Type2& t2) //Line 20
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(t2) { std::cout<<"Test2::Type1, Type2\n";}

    Test2(const Type1& t1,
          const typename Type2::a_type& x,
          const typename Type2::b_type& y)
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(x,y) { std::cout<<"Test2::Type1, X, Y\n";}

};
```

For getting `TypeX` and `TypeY` it's useful to export them so you can use them in `Test2` as shown above.

```
template<class TypeA, class TypeB>
struct Test
{
    typedef TypeA a_type;
    typedef TypeB b_type;

    // and using them, to show their meaning
    a_type t1obj;
    b_type t2obj;

    Test(const a_type& t1, const b_type& t2)
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(t2) {std::cout<<"Test::Type1, Type2\n";}
};
```

Be sure to read [Where to put the "template" and "typename" on dependent names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names) to understand why and when to use `typename` before type names like above.

Comment: But, why doesn't template template arguments work here to catch the arguments provided to Type2?? Could you also explicate the reason for that error I mentioned?

Comment: I guess C++0x variadic templates would be pretty useful here, `Test2` wouldn't have to know anything about the arguments needed by `Type2`'s constructor.

Comment: @Ben correct. We could write a partial specialization of `Test2` which will deduce the template arguments automagically, without relying on fixed named typedefs to get them.

Comment: @Saurabh it's like expecting a function pointer to give you the value of its arguments it is called with. That makes no sense, because you can call a function multiple times with different argument values. `void f(void(*pf)(int a)) { int i = a; /* this doesn't work for similar reasons */ }`. Just like you can instantiate a template with multiple argument values. The declaration of your template template parameter can equivalently be written as `template<typename, typename> class Type2`. The inner parameter names have no meaning.

Comment: So, using type parameters is the only way out in this case? Nothing else comes to rescue?

Comment: @Saurabh to the rescue for what? You haven't presented an ultimate goal.

Comment: @Saurabh: Template template arguments can't come with arguments.  The template they're passed to provides the arguments.

Comment: @Johannes: The goal was to create Test2 that would provide 2 constructors to the users as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Saurabh: Are you now asking about the case where you can't change `Test` to add the typedefs?  See Reinderien's answer, but note that the keyword `typename` needs to be taken out four times before it will be accepted by a compliant compiler.

Comment: @Ben: I got that from Schaub's comment.

Comment: @Ben: Seen his post. That surely gives me another way to achieve the same, but to me, Schaub's solution is far better.

Comment: @Johannes: Great answer. Hugh, the template god has spoken ;)

Comment: @Saurabh. You're using  `Test2<int, Test<int, char> >`  , not  `Test2<int, Test >`    . This is the different between a template-template and a full-blown type.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors with this, but the main error seems to be that

```
Test2<int, Test<int, char> >
```

is not how you pass a template template parameter. This would be passed using

```
Test2<int, Test>
```

That is because `Test` is a *template* but `Test<int, char>` is a *type* (generated from that template.)

Answer (score 0):

`Type1` is a type, `Type2` is a template. What exactly do you think `TypeX` and `TypeY` are defined? Inside the line `template<typename TypeX, typename TypeY> class Type2 >`, they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class TypeA, class TypeB>
struct Test
{
    TypeA t1obj;
    TypeB t2obj;
    Test(const TypeA& t1, const TypeB& t2)
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(t2) {std::cout<<"Test::Type1, Type2\n";}
};


template<class Type1, typename TypeX, typename TypeY,
         template <typename TypeXi, typename TypeYi> class Type2>
struct Test2
{
    Type1 t1obj;
    Type2<typename TypeX, typename TypeY> t2obj; //Line 17

    Test2(const Type1& t1,
          const Type2<typename TypeX, typename TypeY>& t2) //Line 20
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(t2) { std::cout<<"Test2::Type1, Type2\n";}

    Test2(const Type1& t1,
          const TypeX& x,
          const TypeY& y)
        : t1obj(t1), t2obj(x,y) { std::cout<<"Test2::Type1, X, Y\n";}

};

int main()
{
    Test<int, char> obj1(1,'a');

    Test2<int, int, char, Test> strangeobj1(10,obj1);
    Test2<int, int, char, Test> strangeobj2(1,2,'b');

}
```

Comment: It's `Type2<TypeX, TypeY>`, not `Type2<typename TypeX, typename TypeY>`.  `TypeX` and `TypeY` are not dependent names.

Comment: Perhaps. The compiler doesn't seem to care.

Comment: @Ben see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231502/typename-template-and-dependent-names . They are dependent unqualified names. That's why it's syntactically invalid. Please let me hear your opinion on that FAQ entry.

Comment: @Johannes: Um, yeah.  Either way, they're not qualified by a template parameter, so `typename` is invalid.  @Reinderien: Your compiler is not standard compliant.

Comment: @Johannes: FAQ looks good. Only improvement I could suggest is an explanation of why `typename` appears only once, always to the left, away from the type it modifies, while `template` appears in the middle of the scope chain and potentially multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

`Test<int, char>` is not a match for `template<typename TypeX, typename TypeY> class Type2`

The first one is an instantiation of a template class, it does not accept any parameters.  The second one is a template class pattern accepting two parameters.